# Registry access errors ACCESS DENIED

Tags: windows-10, procmon

I have a Windows application that has worked in the past on Windows 10 but now crashes on start-up. I have done some investigations with Process Monitor (PROCMON) and established that there are a significant number of ACCESS DENIED errors during the short period the application runs before it crashes.

As you can see these mostly seem to relate to **SystemCertificates** or **EnterpriseCertificates**

The user for each of these vents is what I recognise as myself on the system. The account has Administrator privileges. I have also tried running the application itself "as an Administrator" but it still crashes.

What are my next steps towards diagnosing and fixing the problem?

Thanks.

```
RegOpenKey      HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters  ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: All Access
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA  ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA  ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\CA   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\CA   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\CA   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\CA   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed  ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed  ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\AuthRoot ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\AuthRoot ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Root    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Root ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Root ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Root ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Root ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\SmartCardRoot    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\SmartCardRoot    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPeople   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\TrustedPeople    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\TrustedPeople    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\TrustedPeople    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\TrustedPeople    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\trust    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\trust    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\trust    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\trust    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\trust   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\trust   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\trust    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\trust    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\trust    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\trust    ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed  ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed  ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
RegCreateKey    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed   ACCESS DENIED   Desired Access: Read/Write, Delete
```

Comment: I don't think these errors are relevant. Do you own the code of the application ? It seems that this app connects to a remote server or something like that, is this correct ? If yes try to capture network trafic too. Don't focus on the errors only, take into account what the app was able to do successfully before crashing.

Comment: No, it is a proprietary application. They don't believe it is an issue with the software per se. It should not be accessing any remote server. In fact, it runs on a different machine I have - to the same Windows10 build. Which makes me think it might be a security or permissions issue. but I don't want to lead your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the Result summary (excluding SUCCESS)

Value Count
NAME NOT FOUND 800
BUFFER OVERFLOW 767
REPARSE 399
FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS 98
ACCESS DENIED 65
PATH NOT FOUND 57
NO MORE ENTRIES 52
NO SUCH FILE 18
BUFFER TOO SMALL 13
NAME COLLISION 4
END OF FILE 2
NO MORE FILES 1

Comment: You should filter on the process only and read the "success" too, it can help you finding what was the last operation before crashing. Then, add a filter on Category -> Is -> Write to see if the app writes to a log file before crashing. Read the Windows event log too.